# Why is $z\mapsto |z|$ not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone explain to me why the absolute value function $f(z)=|z|$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ even though Cauchy-Riemann conditions are true at $(0,0)$ (using $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$)?

Comment: The partial derivatives in the Caucy-Riemann equations do not even exist at $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there's no linear approximation of $|z|$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, in the sense that
$$|z|=az+o(|z|)\quad \text{for some } a\in\mathbf C.$$

Answer (score 0):

first principle $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{h}$. consider the two paths. along real axis and imaginary axis. the $u_x,u_y,v_x$ and $v_y$ must be continuous along with C-R equation at $z=0$.

Comment: So its not continious on 0,0 and not differentiable as a conclusion?

Comment: let me check the theorem.

Comment: It *is* continuous at $0$, because of the *triangle inequality* (2nd form).

Comment: I was telling about the continuity of partial derivatives.

Comment: yes, it is continuous.

Comment: The partial derivatives $u_x$ and $u_y$ do not exist at $z=0$.

Comment: so it canot be continuous at $z=0$. right?

Comment: Correct. I see your point: "it" refers to any one of $u_x$ and $u_y$. It seems that in [JJohnarios's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585584/why-is-z-mapsto-z-not-differentiable-at-0-0#comment5337482_2585586) "it" refers to $f(z)$.

Comment: Am I go wrong anywhere? can you please help me. @Jack

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: did you get anything from the linked question?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: the function $f(z)=|z|$ is continuous anywhere. But it is not complex differentiable at $z=0$ since the partial derivatives $u_x$ and $u_y$ do not exist (and thus the C-R equations do not hold).

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view: because  $f(x,y) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)$ is not even $\Bbb R$-differentiable at $(0,0)$. Think of the vertex of a cone, for example.

If by any chance it were differentiable at the desired point, one would have to check that the Jacobian matrix at the point defines a $\Bbb C$-linear map. In other words, the matrix would have to comute with $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}. $$